# Expected value of sum of elements of a subset of $\{1,..n\}$

Tags: probability

Choose a subset $A$ of $\{1,...,n\}$ at random such that random variable $|A|$ has a uniform distribution. Let $X$ be the random variable equal to the sum of the elements of $A$. What is $E[A]$?

---

The problem is obviously very easy if you understand what expected value is and the probability law associated to a random variable is. However I feel my understanding of these things is weak so I'm not confident in what I'm saying below.

We have $A=\sum_{k=1}^n k*1_{k \in A}$ hence  $E[A]=\sum_{k=1}^n kP(k \in A)$.

For each $k \in \{1,..n\}$, $P(k \in A)=\sum_{m=0}^nP(|A|=m)P((k \in A)|(|A|=m))=\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{{{n-1}\choose{m-1}}}{{{n}\choose{m}}}=\frac{1}{2}$.

where the second equality uses that $|A|$ is uniformly distributed.

Hence $E[A]=\frac{n(n+1)}{4}$.

---

Is this correct? It seems unrigorous because, in the second equality above, I seem to be assuming that for $|A|$ fixed, all possibilities for $A$ have equal probability of being chosen.

Is there a way to make this more rigorous?

Comment: The problem itself is not well-stated, since it gives the distribution of $|A|$ but does not give how $A$ is chosen according to such constraint. There might be just $n$ fixed subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ from which we make our choice, and in such a case the answer depends on which subsets are fixed.

Comment: Right, so basically I think the problem statement is assuming $|A|$ is uniformly distributed, and among the sets with $|A|$ fixed, the choice of subset is uniformly distributed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Given $|A|=k$, the expected value for the sum $S$ is
$$\sum_{j=1}^{k(n+1)}p(S=j)j$$
(Some terms of this sum may be $0$, but this is irrelevant).

But note that $p(S=j)=p(S=(n+1)k-j)$ so the sum becomes
$$\begin{align}
&p(S=(n+1)k/2)\frac{(n+1)k}2+\sum_{1\le j<(n+1)k/2}p(S=j)(n+1)k\\
&=\frac{k(n+1)}2\underbrace{\left(p(S=(n+1)k/2)+\sum_{1\le j<(n+1)k/2}2p(S=j)\right)}_{=1}\\
&=\frac{k(n+1)}2
\end{align}$$

Now, since $p(|A|=k)=\frac1{n+1}$ for $0\le k\le n$,
$$E[A]=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{n+1}\cdot\frac{k(n+1)}2=\frac{n(n+1)}4$$